# Select logic on two interchangeable columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server 2016, I have a table with two `varchar` columns containing names of things being compared (let's say SUBJECT and COMP). Since the comparison values are the same whether A->B or B->A, there's no point in storing both, so I'm only storing A->B. That brings up a novel problem on `SELECT`. Basically:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable(Subject varchar(50), Comp varchar(50))

INSERT INTO myTable(Subject, Comp) values ('SDSD', 'CFGT')
INSERT INTO myTable(Subject, Comp) values ('FMIP', 'ABLQ')
INSERT INTO myTable(Subject, Comp) values ('FMIP', 'FMIP')

DECLARE @sub varchar(50), @comp varchar(50)
SET @sub = 'ABLQ', @comp = 'FMIP;
```

I can't seem to figure out how to say "Give me a row in which the combination of 'ABLQ' and 'FMIP' can exist in either column, but the two columns must contain both values (in other words, 'ABLQ'/'ABLQ' and 'FMIP'/'FMIP' will not return, but both 'ABLQ'/'FMIP' and 'FMIP'/'ABLQ' would - or I should say either would, because only one of the two would actually exist. I've tried several combinations and can't seem to get it right in the logic department. I end up with something like

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable 
WHERE (Subject = @sub OR Comp = @sub) 
  AND (Subject = @comp OR Comp = @Comp) 
  AND (Subject <> @sub AND Comp <> @comp)
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure both columns aren't equal after you have a row with the correct values:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
WHERE
    (Subject=@sub OR Subject=@comp) AND
    (Comp=@sub OR Comp=@comp) AND
    (Subject <> Comp)
```

Comment: Thank you! God that seems so obvious now, but after 36 hours at the keyboard, I'm not sure what my name is anymore. I really appreciate your help in pointing out the obvious to me.

Answer (score 0):

I would be inclined to write the logic as:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM myTable t
WHERE (Subject = @sub AND Comp = @comp) OR
      (Subject = @comp AND Comp = @sub) ;
```

I find this formulation easier to follow.